# folder structure for a plugin oriented site like wordpress

Tags: plugins, web, directory-structure

i just want to know about the files and folder structure for a site which is a plugin oriented like wordpress or joomla.
my requirement is to develop a site and want to add more functions via plugin or something like features.

what i need is to just add and additional information or functional sessions like in **wordpress**
we can use **All in one SEO packages** it will bypass the title and some other information.
or some other features like Related articles are shown at the bottom of a particular article body.
aam talking about a structure of **wordpress**.

does any one have an Idea please share with me.
hope every one understood my qustion as well.
thank you.

Comment: It would be nice if you posted some of your thoughts so far, that would make it easier to help you develop them further.

Comment: @BerggreenDK, i edited the Question, hope it would be more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think there are many possible solutions.**

It might depend on:

- scalablity (how large do you want it to support plugins and do the reuse parts of each other?)
- vibility (how should the plugin address become visible in the url?)
- deployment (who can add new plugins? is it open for everyone or just certified developers)

You could go for:

**www.domain.xyz/plugins/some_module/**

But what if the plugins arent plugins but becomes default part of the system afterwards?

Then it would be more logical to call them what they are like:

**www.domain.xyz/some_module/**

But then you might get into problems with plugins name like exisiting system folders. Therefore you would need some "reserved" list of foldernames to prevent that.

You could also go for:

**some_module.domain.xyz/**

But that would requiere your webadmin or webserver to support multiple aliases for one website on the other hand, this arhictecture would bring scalability, because you could move the modules to other webhosts later on. But its also more expensive work in the development + its hard to make it "user/developer controlled" as this could grow.

You could have a look at how FaceBook is handling Applications too. Thats a plugin interface too. Slow, but implemented.

Comment: sorry about the spelling people.